# What is the value of $\sin(\sqrt{-1})$ ? What does it signify?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I used the formula $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, substituting $x = i$, we get $1/e = \cos(i) + i\sin(i)$, as real part on LHS $= 0$, $\sin(i) = 0$, is this correct? I don't really understand trigonometric formulas with imaginary inputs.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! How do you know $\cos i$ is the real part?

Comment: the argument doesnt work because its not true that $\sin(i)\in\mathbb R$, Try using $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Comment: Yes, I assumed cos(√-1) to be real

Comment: $\sqrt{-1}$ does not exist. $i$ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. It would be correct if $\cos(i)$ and $\sin(i)$ were real numbers, but they are not. Actually,$$\cos(i)=\frac{e+\frac1e}{2}\text{ and }\sin(i)=\frac{e-\frac1e}2i.$$

Comment: Okay, I get this now. Thank you.

Comment: Equivalently, $\cos i=\cosh 1$ and $\sin i=i\sinh 1$

Comment: @AbhinavRawal If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)$$ and $$e^{-i(x+iy)}=e^{y}(\cos x-i\sin x).$$

From this,

$$\cos(x+iy)=\cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y$$ and $$\sin(x+iy)=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin i=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{i^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\dfrac{e^{-1}-e}{2i}$.
The first equality comes from the Taylor series;   the second can be gotten from Euler's formula.